# how to get the response of a graphQl call in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, graphql, graphql-mutation

I need to get the response of a graphQl call that is executed in a selenium test (Java) in order to get the id that is generated in the database.

Example:

```
mutation {
  createWidget(designID: 701, contentID: 1935, layoutPos: "{\"TV\":{\"x\":117,\"y\":66,\"w\":60,\"h\":33}}", pos: 1) {
    error
    ok
    id
    __typename
  }
}
```

When executing this query you would need to get the ids created.

I expect a string with the mutation to be able to separate the necessary ids.